# The trait bound `&str: From<MyType>` is not satisfied even though I implemented `From<&str> for MyType`

Tags: rust

I tried to implement run length encoding with the help of `From` and `Into`. The idea is I am going to implement only `from` and get `into` implementation for free.

```
extern crate regex;

use regex::Regex;

struct RLE(pub String);

impl<'a> From<&'a str> for RLE {
    fn from(s: &str) -> Self {
        let reg = Regex::new(r"(\d*)([\w\s])").unwrap();
        let mut accum = String::new();
        for c in reg.captures_iter(s) {
            let n = c.get(1).unwrap().as_str().parse::<usize>().unwrap_or(1);
            let c = c.get(2).unwrap().as_str();
            accum.push_str(&c.repeat(n));
        }
        RLE(accum)
    }
}
```

> decode("2ab3c") => "aabccc"

```
pub fn decode(s: &str) -> String {
    let RLE(string) = RLE::from(s);
    string
}
```

> encode("aabccc") => "2ab3c"

```
pub fn encode(s: &str) -> String {
    let string: &'static str = RLE(s.to_string()).into();
    string.to_string()
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `&str: std::convert::From<RLE>` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:26:51
   |
26 |     let string: &'static str = RLE(s.to_string()).into();
   |                                                   ^^^^ the trait `std::convert::From<RLE>` is not implemented for `&str`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::convert::Into<&str>` for `RLE`
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've got it backwards.  `From<&str> for RLE` cannot *possibly* be used to do an `RLE` → `&str` conversion.  That's like using a recipie to bake a cake to deconstruct it back into its constituent ingredients.

`From<&str> for RLE` implies the existence of `Into<RLE> for &str`.  It means you can do `a_str.into()` rather than `RLE::from(a_str)`.  You can work this out by looking at [the documentation for `Into`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.Into.html), which lists the following implementation:

```
impl<T, U> Into<U> for T where U: From<T>
```

If you substitute the types for your `From` implementation (with `U = RLE` and `T = &str`), you get:

```
impl Into<RLE> for &str where RLE: From<&str>
```

What you're trying to do with `REL(s.to_string()).into()` would require `impl Into<&str> for RLE`.

Answer (score 5):

> The idea is I am going to implement only from and get into implementation for free...

That works!

You can use `From`, as in

```
pub fn decode(s: &str) -> String {
    let RLE(string) = RLE::from(s);
    string
}
```

and you can use `Into`, as in

```
pub fn decode_using_into(s: &str) -> String {
    let RLE(string) = s.into();
    string
}
```

> But I get following error

Well, as DK. said, Rust won't implement one algorithm from another. You'll have to do it yourself.

Comment: Eh, that sucks. I have thought that there might be some deriving magic (like Debug) that would implement the isomorphism automatically...

Comment: derive(Debug) works on a relatively simple syntax tree of *fields*, it implements debug formatting *for simple types*, while the complex types have to implement it themselves. Deriving from the *code*, and that of a complex *library*, and *reversing its algorithm*... these are, like, *infinitely* more compex than what derive(Debug) does!